# How to locate a link with an img on the same row in a grid with xpath

Tags: image, xpath, hyperlink

I need to click a link in a grid that contains a particular img on the same row.  I can easily find the correct img I want with:

`//img[@src='./assets/images/not_evaluated.svg']`.

However, when I issue the click with it, it doesn't work because the image is not clickable.  However, the same row contains the link I want to click.  The xpath to the clickable link is:

`//a[@class='veracodelink']//span[contains(text(),'Static Scan')]`.

I need to combine these 2 xpaths to get the correct link to click.  I have tried many different things and combinations, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block containing the HTML of the page. Without that, it's impossible to answer the question because we don't know what "the same row" means. Is it a row of a table? Are they elements in a CSS grid layout?

Comment: Hi Conal - It is an angular grid.  The HTML of the page is pretty big - let me know if you still need that.   So I'm looking for 2 elements in the same row of an angular grid to identify it.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, I'm trying to find the row that contains a particular img, and the corresponding link on the same row so I can click it.

Comment: As I understand it, an "angular grid" is a generic kind of UI with many different implementations. You don't say which one you are working with. Please include in your question either a link to the HTML, or  a code block containing a sample of the HTML. If it's too large, please make a cut-down version, including only the HTML element that's the container for the grid, and including only a sample of the rows in the grid, if there are too many rows. Even just one row!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the image and the link are inside the same `tr` element, you could combine them like this:

```
//tr[.//img[@src='./assets/images/not_evaluated.svg']]//a[@class='veracodelink']//span[contains(text(),'Static Scan')]
```

Explained: `//tr[...]` here selects the correct row containing the image, and the rest then selects the clickable element relative to that.

If they are inside something else than `tr`, adjust accordingly.

Comment: Jukka - That would select the images and not the links - I posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured this out myself: The xpath I needed is:

```
//div//vc-link//a[@class='veracodelink']//span[contains(text(), 'Static Scan')][../../../../../..//img[@src='./assets/images/not_evaluated.svg']]
```